# GWT HighCharts Moxieapps - How to get color of series in the tooltip and prevent tooltip going off the screen

Tags: gwt, tooltip, highcharts

We are using Moxieapps Highchart v1.3.0
we have two requirements in displaying the tooltip for line chart.

i. the x axis is datetime axis. we need to format the date displayed in the tooltip. So using ToolTipData, we formatted the date in tooltip. But the colors of the series name in the tooltip is lost. The tooltip is shared. How to display the series name in the tooltip with the respective color?

ii. Our tooltip may grow in height/width. In such scenario, the tooltip goes off the screen i.e half of the tooltip is visible and other half goes off the screen. I used html tag to wrap text in the tooltip. I tried applying width to the html tag. But there's no effect. How to prevent tooltip going off the screen?

Please find the code snippet
setToolTip(new ToolTip().setShared(true).setCrosshairs(true).setFormatter(new ToolTipFormatter() {
      public String format(final ToolTipData toolTipData)
      {
        final StringBuilder tooltipContent = new StringBuilder();
        String formattedDate = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(
              new Date(toolTipData.getXAsLong(0)));

```
    tooltipContent.append("<b>").append(formattedDate)
      .append("</b>");
    for (int i = 0; i < toolTipData.getPointsLength(); i++)
    {
      tooltipContent.append("<br />").append("<span>")
        .append(toolTipData.getSeriesName(i)).append(":").append(toolTipData.getYAsDouble(i));

      tooltipContent.append("</span>");
    }
    return tooltipContent.toString();
  }
}));
```

Kindly help in the issues.
Thanks in Advance